# Get Parameter from URL and use it in dictionary

Tags: javascript, html

i have basically 0 programming experience. So here is my question. I am Using a JS to get some Parameters from URL and use it with the HTML, and it works.

This is the code:

```
function qs(search_for) {
    var query = window.location.search.substring(1);
    var parms = query.split('&');
    for (var i=0; i<parms.length; i++) {
        var pos = parms[i].indexOf('=');
        if (pos > 0  && search_for == parms[i].substring(0,pos)) {
            return parms[i].substring(pos+1);;
        }
    }
    return "";
}
```

and in HTML

```
<script type="text/javascript">document.write(qs("name"));</script>
```

Now, let's say I want to use the Value of the Parameters to generate a specific Text on the page. But I do not want to use the Parameter itself, but rather use a kind of Dictionary, to match a Parameter to a String.

for Example 
a1 : "Good morning"
b2 : "Good evening"

I have tried something linke this, with no success, can someone help?:

```
function qs(search_for) {
   var dict = {}
   dict[a1] = "Good morning";
   dict[b2] = "Good evening";

     var query = window.location.search.substring(1);
     var parms = query.split('&');
     for (var i=0; i<parms.length; i++) {
         var pos = parms[i].indexOf('=');
         if (pos > 0  && search_for == parms[i].substring(0,pos)) {
             if parms[i].substring(pos+1) in dict {
                return dict[parms[i].substring(pos+1)];;
             }
         }
     }
     return "";
 }
```

Thanks in advance!
L

EDIT: Just to be clear, I do not want to read Parameters "a1" and "b2". I rather want that when a certain Parameter equals "a1" the function returns "Good morning" and when a certain parameter equals "b2" the function returns "Good evening"

Comment: Have looked into https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URL/searchParams ?

Answer (score 1):

You do this:

```
function getParam(param){
  var both = location.search.replace('?', '').split('&');
  for(var i=0,a,l=both.length; i<l; i++){
    a = both[i].split('=');
    if(a[0] === encodeURIComponent(param)){
      return decodeURIComponent(a[1]);
    }
  }
  return undefined;
}
var useInDict = getParam('a1');
```

Assumes raw url encode.

Answer (score 0):

```
function parseGETfromUrl ( query = location.search.substring( 1 ) ) {
    let parameters = {};
    for ( const [ name, value ] of new URLSearchParams( query ) ) parameters[name] = value;
    return parameters;
}

//Test code
let paramsString = "q=URLUtils.searchParams&topic=api";
parseGETfromUrl( paramsString ); // { q: "URLUtils.searchParams", topic: "api" }
parseGETfromUrl(); //Same result as above, when url ends with "?q=URLUtils.searchParams&topic=api"
```

Heading function parseGETfromUrl returns an object which contains information of url query string.